# sonata and single page

Tags: symfony, sonata

i'm newbie of sonata,

i have a ContentTestAdmin with entity etc, that can only contains 4 record
- record 1
- record 2
- record 3
- record 4

i already disabled create and delete function

```
public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
  $collection->remove('create')->remove('delete');
}
```

but i need to change link on dashboard and on the left menu:

actually i put on my service.yml

```
 admin.comuni:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\ContentTestAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\ContentTest, ~]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Content Test, group: Main Section }
```

and i see on dashboard the box with title "Content" and inside the "Content Test" with link to the list

i would erase this part and see like

Content test
- record 1 title > with link to 1/edit
- record 2 title > with link to 2/edit
- record 3 title > with link to 3/edit
- record 4 title > with link to 4/edit

same issue for the left menu, a folder named Content test with 4 link inside

is possible? thank you

Comment: check out https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html . If it's  overwhelming , override the template.  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig and add your custom links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be configuring your admin menu in your app/config.yml.

Here is an example :

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            content_test:
                label: Content
                icon:  '<i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>'
                items:
                    - route: 'route_to_record1'
                      route_params: { id: 1 } #id of record 1
                      label: Record 1
                    - route: 'route_to_record_2'
                      route_params: { id: 2 }
                      label: Record 2
```

To find out the route to a record execute the command

```
app/console (bin/console on sf3) debug:router
```

This will show you all the routes existing in your app just find the route sonata admin generated for your ContentAdmin for show or edit or whatever you need( ex: admin_content_test_show).then just fill route_params with the id of the desired record.

(you can use that to point to any route in your app and prefill any parameters of that route)

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: very helpful! thank you, in the side bar it works,  but there is not link in dashboard, how i can fix it?

Comment: To edit the content of the dashboard look at standard_layout.html.twig.