# How to have two list with one admin class sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Can you help to configure two list in one class Admin so I need to override this function two times :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('id', null, array(
            'header_style' => 'width: 5%; text-align: center',
            'row_align' => 'center'
        ))
        ->add('nom', null, array(
            'header_style' => 'width: 35%; text-align: center',
            'row_align' => 'center'
        ))  
        ->add('dateCreation', null, array(
            'header_style' => 'width: 35%; text-align: center',
            'row_align' => 'center'
        ));
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise ? What are this two times ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443478/custom-action-leading-to-filtered-list-with-multiple-parameters/41575029?noredirect=1#comment70420317_41575029

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here for how to configure custom filtered lists  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41143235/5758328 in your admin menu.

If you really want to have two separate `configureListFields()` method what you can do is make a second admin for the same entity.

like so:

```
app.admin.bar:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\BarAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Bar, BlastCoreBundle:CRUD ]
    tags:
        - name: sonata.admin
          manager_type: orm
          group: admin

 app.admin.bar2:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\BarAdmin2
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Bar, BlastCoreBundle:CRUD ]
    tags:
        - name: sonata.admin
          manager_type: orm
          group: admin
```

Then just create the second admin class and do whatever you want with it.